# Portable MiKTeX Packages Management

Tags: packages, miktex, import

I have already installed MiKTeX 2.9 (Not a portable version) in my computer.

I have already had portable MiKTeX 2.9 in my USB.

I want to use my portable version.

But it lack of some packages.

Whenever it requires, I need the internet connection to download missing packages.

I am really bored to download the missing packages one by one from time to time.

Is there any trick to import all the packages from non-portable MikTeX to portable MikTex?

Answer (score 4):

There is another possibility.

1. Download the whole contents of the directory [mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/) in a local directory.
2. Link the package repository in the MiKTeX Package Manager to this folder, through the command "Change Package Repository" in the "Repository" menu.

[image]

In this way you can keep a "light" distribution and install packages when needed without an internet connection.

### P.S.

The first step can be done with the MiKTeX Installer, but I'd rather use a "download manager" to speed up the download... Anyway, if you already have the "complete" version installed, you should have these files somewhere in your PC.

Comment: What about MiKTeX updates(for portable version) at that time one may need internet ?

Comment: @texenthusiast if you need to update the packages, you obviously need an internet connection!

Comment: Any thoughts: Does a MiKTeX(Portable version) Work on a Linux OS Via [`wine`](http://www.winehq.org/) ?

Comment: @texenthusiast I've no idea :-(

Comment: It works fine by combining all methods above.

Comment: 1.) MiKTeX Package Manager

Comment: 2.) Repository->Change Package Repository->Packages shall be installed from a directory.->Next->Browse.....

Comment: 3.) Choose the downloaded full package non-poratable MiKTex->Finish

Comment: 4.)From menu bar: Edit->Select Installable Packages->Install(Press on the + sign)

Comment: Wait until finish :)

Comment: @OLSAY I meant to leave things as they are and let MiKTeX install them when needed... so to have a light portable distro!

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get a portable complete MiKTeX is the following way:

1. Start portable MiKTeX
2. Connect to internet
3. Start the portable package manager of your portable MiKTeX
4. select all packages to be updated
5. wait until the download is done

Comment: Is there "full(not-Basic) MiKTeX" installation for Portable version instead of `selecting all packages:4th step`.

Comment: As 16gb usb does not cost much, I was thinking to install `full MiKTeX` in the same lines of OP.Thanks for all.